# How to pass CSS class names in React JS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to change the width of a component whenever I click a button from another component

This is the button in BiCarret:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { BiCaretLeft } from "react-icons/bi";

const SideBar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <BiCaretLeft 
        className={`${
          open ? "w-72" : "w-20"
        } bg-red-400 absolute cursor-pointer -right-3 top-5 border rounded-full`}
        color="#fff"
        size={25}
        onClick={setOpen(!true)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

and this is the component I want to change the width on click

```
import "./App.css";
import SideBar from "./components/SideBar/SideBar";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app flex">
      <aside className="h-screen bg-slate-700"> // change the width here
        <SideBar />
      </aside>
      <main className="flex-1 h-screen"></main>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple solutions, either:

1. Create context
   Crete context and store Open value in it, change it on click and in App react to it.
2. Dom manipulation
   In app add ID to element you would like to change and onClick in the other component use `document.getElementById(THE_ID).classList.add("new-class-for-increased-width")` which gets the DOM element and adds class to it.